# Dynamically Generate Angular material Input Field by javascript (check reference code it is not working style is not working)

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material-6

This code Javascript helps me generate a new html code when i drag and drop to new box but with angular material style is not coming with it ... 
    i have included in app.module.ts and made new angular-material.ts but its not working.

if include

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

in dashboard.html it working excellent but when i do this with Javascript it doesn't work as expected .. style doesn't show.

any suggestions?

```js
function nameFunction() {
          var r = document.createElement('div');
          var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
          r.setAttribute("value", "Name");
          r.innerHTML = '<form class="example-form"><mat-form-field class="example-full-width"> <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi"> </mat-form-field> <mat-form-field class="example-full-width"> <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea> </mat-form-field> </form>';
          y.setAttribute("type", "text");
          y.style.float = "left";
          r.style.float = "left";
          r.style.margin = "1%";
          var g = document.createElement("i");
          g.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-times-circle text-danger pl-2 pr-2");
          increment();
          y.setAttribute("Name", "textelement_" + i);
          r.appendChild(y);
          g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
          r.appendChild(g);
          r.setAttribute("id", "label" + i);
    
    
          document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
        }
```

```html
    
        <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" [style.background]="color" id="newArea" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" [style.background]="color1" style=" padding: 10px; min-height: 550px;"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM manipulation to add elements does not add Angular components. The element added to the DOM is only DOM, it will not include the Angular wiring. You need to manipulate DOM the 'Angular' way. See the Angular docs on [adding components dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)